# Stochastic indicator formula

Tags: python, math, algorithmic-trading, trading

I am scraping a number every 1 minute and I want to know when this number changes by a lot compared to it's previous values. I've decided to use the Stochastic indicator (maybe not the best way).

I am trying to implement the [Stochastic](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stochasticoscillator.asp#:%7E:text=A%20stochastic%20oscillator%20is%20a,moving%20average%20of%20the%20result.) indicator in python **but the results is always 100**. I think i am doing something wrong.

**The formula:**

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
def get_k():
    global c_last_count
    c_last_count = int(data[0])
    highest = int(max(data))
    lowest = int(min(data))
    try:
        k = ((c_last_count - lowest) / (highest - lowest)) * 100
    except:
        k = 0

    k_arr.insert(0, k)

    if len(k_arr) >= 0:
        k_smoothing_3 = np.mean(k_arr[0:3])
        print("k_smoothing_3 ", k_smoothing_3)
        global stoch
        stoch.insert(0, k_smoothing_3)
        print("stoch ", k_smoothing_3)
        store_stoch(k_smoothing_3)
```

**Data `k_arr`:**

```
['5169', '5169', '5168', '5168', '5167', '5166', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5164', '5165', '5164', '5163', '5162', '5163', '5162', '5162', '5162', '5163', '5162', '5162', '5160', '5160', '5162', '5162', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5159', '5159', '5159', '5159', '5158', '5156', '5155', '5154', '5154', '5154', '5153', '5153', '5153', '5153', '5153', '5154', '5154', '5153', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5151', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5149', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5151', '5151', '5151', '5151', '5151', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5153', '5152', '5151', '5151', '5152', '5151', '5150', '5148', '5148', '5148', '5148', '5148', '5147', '5147', '5147', '5147', '5146', '5146', '5145', '5144', '5145', '5145', '5145', '5145', '5144', '5144', '5144', '5144', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5142', '5142', '5141', '5141', '5140', '5140', '5140', '5140', '5139', '5139', '5139', '5139', '5140', '5140', '5140', '5139',  '5008', '5007', '5007', '5006', '5004', '5004', '5003', '5002', '5002', '5002', '5002', '5003', '5002', '5002', '5000', '5000', '5000', '5000', '5000', '5000', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4997', '4997', '4998', '4996', '4996', '4997', '4996', '4996', '4996', '4996', '4997', '4997', '4997', '4996', '4996', '4996', '4995', '4995', '4993', '4993', '4994', '4994', '4994', '4993', '4993', '4992', '4992', '4992', '4992', '4990', '4990', '4988', '4989', '4990', '4991', '4991', '4992', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4991', '4991', '4991', '4991', '4992', '4991', '4989', '4989', '4989', '4988', '4987', '4986', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4987', '4987', '4986', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4984', '4984', '4984', '4984', '4984', '4983', '4983', '4983', '4983', '4982', '4980', '4980', '4980', '4981', '4979', '4978', '4977', '4976', '4977', '4977', '4976', '4977', '4977', '4976', '4974', '4973', '4971', '4971', '4970', '4970', '4970', '4969', '4969', '4968', '4968', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4965', '4963', '4964', '4965', '4965', '4965', '4964', '4964', '4962', '4962', '4962', '4961', '4960', '4960', '4959', '4959', '4959', '4960', '4959', '4959', '4958', '4958', '4958', '4958', '4958', '4956', '4955', '4955', '4954', '4954', '4954', '4954']
```

Comment: Suggestions: Do **not** use global variables. Include the variables that are needed as input in the arguments of the function (between the two brackets on the `def` line). For the output, use the `return` keyword. That would make it **a lot** easier for other people to read and understand your code.

Comment: `highest = int(max(data))` That line is highly suspicious. You're converting the result to `int` because `data` is a list of strings rather than a list of ints. But if it's a list of strings, how is `max` going to be able to identify the maximum value correctly? You need to convert to `int` **before** calling `max`, not after. String comparison is lexicographical: for instance, with strings `'934' > '5169'`, whereas with ints `934 < 5169`.

Comment: Anyway, it's hard to help you right now, because we don't know what is what. It appears you have several lists: `data`, `k_arr`, `stoch`. The formula that you're trying to implement is only expecting one list. The code you've shown us appears to do a lot more than just calculate the value for that formula.

Comment: Regarding "the result is always 100": you should expect the result to be 100 when the most recent closing price is the highest price of the 14 previous sessions, and to be less than 100 when the most recent closing price is not the highest price.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- Do **not** use global variables. Include the variables that are needed as input in the arguments of the function (between the two brackets on the `def` line). For the output, use the `return` keyword. That would make it **a lot** easier for other people to read and understand your code.
- `highest = int(max(data))`: That line is highly suspicious. You're converting the result to `int` because `data` is a list of strings rather than a list of integers. But if it's a list of strings, how is `max` going to be able to identify the maximum value correctly? You need to convert to `int` **before** calling `max`, not after. String comparison is lexicographical: for instance, with strings `'934' > '5169'`, whereas with ints `934 < 5169`.
- It appears your function manipulates several lists: `data`, `k_arr`, `stoch`. The formula that you're trying to implement is only expecting one list. The code you've shown us appears to do a lot more than just calculate the value for that formula.
- Regarding *"the result is always 100"*: you should expect the result to be 100 when the most recent closing price is the highest price of the 14 previous sessions, and to be less than 100 when the most recent closing price is not the highest price.
- When `L14 == H14`, you cannot divide by `(H14 - L14)` because that would be a division by 0. Currently, your code handles that with a `try / except` block, which chooses the arbitrary value 0 as the indicator in this case. Note that the value 0 is also the value of the indicator when `C == L14`. I think a distinction should be made and since I see no reason, according to your formula, to return 0 when `L14 == H14`, your function could return "not a number" when the indicator cannot be calculated because of the division by 0.

With all that in mind, I suggest to rewrite your function so that it accepts a list of `int` as argument; extracts the last 14 values from that list; calculates L14 and H14 and C; calculates K; and returns K with the `return` keyword.

```py
def stochastic_indicator(data):
    last_14 = data[-14:]
    l14 = min(last_14)
    h14 = max(last_14)
    c = last_14[-1]
    if h14 > l14:
        return 100 * (c - l14) / (h14 - l14)
    else:
        return float('nan')

# TESTING

str_data = ['5169', '5169', '5168', '5168', '5167', '5166', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5165', '5164', '5165', '5164', '5163', '5162', '5163', '5162', '5162', '5162', '5163', '5162', '5162', '5160', '5160', '5162', '5162', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5160', '5159', '5159', '5159', '5159', '5158', '5156', '5155', '5154', '5154', '5154', '5153', '5153', '5153', '5153', '5153', '5154', '5154', '5153', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5151', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5149', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5150', '5151', '5151', '5151', '5151', '5151', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5152', '5153', '5152', '5151', '5151', '5152', '5151', '5150', '5148', '5148', '5148', '5148', '5148', '5147', '5147', '5147', '5147', '5146', '5146', '5145', '5144', '5145', '5145', '5145', '5145', '5144', '5144', '5144', '5144', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5143', '5142', '5142', '5141', '5141', '5140', '5140', '5140', '5140', '5139', '5139', '5139', '5139', '5140', '5140', '5140', '5139',  '5008', '5007', '5007', '5006', '5004', '5004', '5003', '5002', '5002', '5002', '5002', '5003', '5002', '5002', '5000', '5000', '5000', '5000', '5000', '5000', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4999', '4997', '4997', '4998', '4996', '4996', '4997', '4996', '4996', '4996', '4996', '4997', '4997', '4997', '4996', '4996', '4996', '4995', '4995', '4993', '4993', '4994', '4994', '4994', '4993', '4993', '4992', '4992', '4992', '4992', '4990', '4990', '4988', '4989', '4990', '4991', '4991', '4992', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4993', '4991', '4991', '4991', '4991', '4992', '4991', '4989', '4989', '4989', '4988', '4987', '4986', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4987', '4987', '4986', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4985', '4984', '4984', '4984', '4984', '4984', '4983', '4983', '4983', '4983', '4982', '4980', '4980', '4980', '4981', '4979', '4978', '4977', '4976', '4977', '4977', '4976', '4977', '4977', '4976', '4974', '4973', '4971', '4971', '4970', '4970', '4970', '4969', '4969', '4968', '4968', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4967', '4965', '4963', '4964', '4965', '4965', '4965', '4964', '4964', '4962', '4962', '4962', '4961', '4960', '4960', '4959', '4959', '4959', '4960', '4959', '4959', '4958', '4958', '4958', '4958', '4958', '4956', '4955', '4955', '4954', '4954', '4954', '4954']

int_data = list(map(int, str_data))
#        = [5169, 5169, 5168, 5168, 5167, 5166, 5165, 5165, 5165, 5165, 5165, 5165, 5165, 5165, 5164, 5165, 5164, 5163, 5162, 5163, 5162, 5162, 5162, 5163, 5162, 5162, 5160, 5160, 5162, 5162, 5160, 5160, 5160, 5160, 5160, 5160, 5160, 5159, 5159, 5159, 5159, 5158, 5156, 5155, 5154, 5154, 5154, 5153, 5153, 5153, 5153, 5153, 5154, 5154, 5153, 5152, 5152, 5152, 5151, 5150, 5150, 5150, 5149, 5150, 5150, 5150, 5150, 5150, 5151, 5151, 5151, 5151, 5151, 5152, 5152, 5152, 5152, 5152, 5152, 5152, 5153, 5152, 5151, 5151, 5152, 5151, 5150, 5148, 5148, 5148, 5148, 5148, 5147, 5147, 5147, 5147, 5146, 5146, 5145, 5144, 5145, 5145, 5145, 5145, 5144, 5144, 5144, 5144, 5143, 5143, 5143, 5143, 5143, 5143, 5143, 5143, 5142, 5142, 5141, 5141, 5140, 5140, 5140, 5140, 5139, 5139, 5139, 5139, 5140, 5140, 5140, 5139, 5008, 5007, 5007, 5006, 5004, 5004, 5003, 5002, 5002, 5002, 5002, 5003, 5002, 5002, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 4999, 4999, 4999, 4999, 4999, 4999, 4999, 4997, 4997, 4998, 4996, 4996, 4997, 4996, 4996, 4996, 4996, 4997, 4997, 4997, 4996, 4996, 4996, 4995, 4995, 4993, 4993, 4994, 4994, 4994, 4993, 4993, 4992, 4992, 4992, 4992, 4990, 4990, 4988, 4989, 4990, 4991, 4991, 4992, 4993, 4993, 4993, 4993, 4993, 4993, 4993, 4991, 4991, 4991, 4991, 4992, 4991, 4989, 4989, 4989, 4988, 4987, 4986, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4987, 4987, 4986, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4985, 4984, 4984, 4984, 4984, 4984, 4983, 4983, 4983, 4983, 4982, 4980, 4980, 4980, 4981, 4979, 4978, 4977, 4976, 4977, 4977, 4976, 4977, 4977, 4976, 4974, 4973, 4971, 4971, 4970, 4970, 4970, 4969, 4969, 4968, 4968, 4967, 4967, 4967, 4967, 4967, 4967, 4967, 4965, 4963, 4964, 4965, 4965, 4965, 4964, 4964, 4962, 4962, 4962, 4961, 4960, 4960, 4959, 4959, 4959, 4960, 4959, 4959, 4958, 4958, 4958, 4958, 4958, 4956, 4955, 4955, 4954, 4954, 4954, 4954]

for t in range(25, 304, 25):
    print('# Stochastic indicator at time t={:3d}: {:6.2f}'.format(t, stochastic_indicator(int_data[:t])))
# Stochastic indicator at time t= 25:   0.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t= 50:   0.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t= 75: 100.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=100:   0.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=125:   0.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=150:   0.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=175:   0.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=200: 100.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=225:  25.00
# Stochastic indicator at time t=250:  14.29
# Stochastic indicator at time t=275:  16.67
# Stochastic indicator at time t=300:   0.00
```

Comment: FYI: code uses assumptions, that were not present in the O/P. How do you know, the prices time-series is not maintained as a reverse-flowing list of values ( inserting the new bar open price before the 1st list-item, next maintaining the current bar "close"-price in the [0]-th position, until the live-bar ends ), which is a practice that many Trading engines (for latency-/performance-/historical-reasons)? Similarly a suggestion to artificially cast NaN as a Stoch()-result is violating the Quant-traditions, as many post-processing indicators on indicators ( IoI-s ) will fail to process NaN-s

Comment: @user3666197 My point about NaN is to make an explicit distinction between situations where the formula evaluates to 0, and situations where the formula cannot be evaluated. I certainly do not claim that NaN is the best output in the situation where h14 == l14. This answer is meant as an answer to a question, with explanations that are meant to be read and understood. I certainly do not intend for this code to be copypasted or used as if it were a standard function from a library.